# SQL Job failing due to an error

Tags: sql-server-2008, jobs

I am no expert with SQL for sure but I am wondering if I could take a swing at this on my own.

I have an SQL job called "Misc Update NAV" that is scheduled to run every day at 7 am, however, when checking the job history I noticed that it has been failing since forever... The errors shown in the logs are two types and depending on the day it triggers either one or two error logs (see examples below)

Can anyone guide me to understand the error, what is the root cause and what might be the resolution also, can anyone explain why some of the error messages are referring at the very end to a night time (00:31:56,0,0,,,,0) when the job is meant to start at 7 am?

Examples:

05/16/2019 07:00:00,Misc Update NAV,Error,0,SMNAVDB,Misc Update NAV,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 99 (Misc overnight NAV UPDATE).  The last step to run was step 1 (Misc Update).,**00:31:56,0,0**,,,,0

05/16/2019 07:00:00,Misc Update NAV,Error,1,SMNAVDB,Misc Update NAV,Misc Update,,Executed as user: SPEED\SQLNAVServiceUser. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Solicitor Name' table 'SQLNavSpeedMedical.dbo.SMES Live$Case Ledger'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 515)  The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.,00:31:56,16,3621,,,,0
05/15/2019 07:00:00,Misc Update NAV,Error,0,SMNAVDB,Misc Update NAV,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 99 (Misc overnight NAV UPDATE).  The last step to run was step 1 (Misc Update).,00:29:48,0,0,,,,0

05/15/2019 07:00:00,Misc Update NAV,Error,1,SMNAVDB,Misc Update NAV,Misc Update,,Executed as user: SPEED\SQLNAVServiceUser. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Solicitor Name' table 'SQLNavSpeedMedical.dbo.SMES Live$Case Ledger'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 515)  The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.,00:29:48,16,3621,,,,0

05/14/2019 07:00:00,Misc Update NAV,Error,0,SMNAVDB,Misc Update NAV,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 99 (Misc overnight NAV UPDATE).  The last step to run was step 1 (Misc Update).,00:28:13,0,0,,,,0
05/14/2019 07:00:00,Misc Update NAV,Error,1,SMNAVDB,Misc Update NAV,Misc Update,,Executed as user: SPEED\SQLNAVServiceUser. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Solicitor Name' table 'SQLNavSpeedMedical.dbo.SMES Live$Case Ledger'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 515)  The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.,00:28:13,16,3621,,,,0

Thanks

Hicham

Comment: it cleary says it `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Solicitor Name' table 'SQLNavSpeedMedical.dbo.SMES Live$Case Ledger'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.`

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comment, error is very clear that job is trying to insert null value into not null column. You need to check definition of table `SMES Live$Case Ledger`. This seems to be under database name  `SQLNavSpeedMedical` and column name is `Solicitor Name`. Table is under default schema dbo.

Please check the DDL of table and you will see column `Solcitor Name` as not null.

Hope this helps.